# What's another word/term for professional speaker?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

i.e. a person who earns a living (or a portion of it) from public speaking.

A single word would be preferred but up to 2 words max since I am working with a word limit myself.

Comment: What's wrong with *professional speaker*?

Comment: Perhaps a lecturer?

Comment: @Mick: Too many characters lol. It's copy for a logo so I wanted to keep it under 12 characters so it remains aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: What's wrong with public speaker?

Comment: If _professional_ is too long, consider the well-known abbreviation "_pro_".

Comment: It is not clear whether what is sought here is a word for some particular kind of professional speakers, or a word that encompasses all of them. No term proposed on this page does the latter, although some are good terms for subsets of them. As the OP appears to have stopped engaging with the site, it is unlikely that the question will be clarified in this respect, so it may as well be closed. Also, single-word-request that incorporate the constraints that are relevant to only one occasion for their use, such as 'no more than 12 characters' are usually frowned upon on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *spokesman*.

> **Spokesman** *noun*
>   A person who makes statements on behalf of a group or individual:
>   ‘a spokesman for Greenpeace’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spokesman)

I'd hazard a guess, though, that people who pay to listen to a speaker do so for the content delivered, rather than the speaking itself. It may be more useful to seek a term relevant to your subject matter.

Comment: As the quoted definition makes clear, a spokesman always speaks on behalf of someone else, which is not true of all professional speakers.

Answer (score 0):

An [orator](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/orator?s=t)? That's about the closest word I could think of.

Comment: Nothing about it implies professional: speaking to earn a living.  The OP asks for a professional speaker, not a public speaker.

Comment: "A person who delivers an oration; a public speaker, especially one of great eloquence"

Comment: In order to achieve eloquence, the person must be a professional at oration.

Comment: No, not professional in the sense of speaking for money. That meaning of pro is not conveyed by *orator*.

Comment: Motivational / Conventional / Professional / Eloquent / Expert Orator?

Answer (score 0):

People who advertise this service on their websites tend to call themselves the following:

***motivational speaker***

Here is one example of many: https://www.jessicacox.com/about-jessica/

Comment: Again, that does not imply that they do it for a living, even if that is often the case.

Comment: @Drew - I have never seen someone billed as a motivational speaker who doesn't charge.  I think the amateurs are called *toastmasters*.

Comment: Maybe you have never seen one. That does not change the fact that a motivational speaker is a speaker who motivates. It is not necessarily one who does so for remuneration. It is the difference between a coach and a professional coach. A professional motivational speaker does it for remuneration. Perhaps someone will come up with a great single-word answer, but not I. I don't know a more accurate or simpler term for the answer than *professional speaker*.

Comment: Even granting that those who are referred to as motivational speakers always charge for their services, they are only a subset of professional speakers.